# How to get all of the IDs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to gather a list (array) of ids in a sector

```
<div id="mydiv">
 <span id='span1'>
 <span id='span2'>
</div>

$("#mydiv").find("span");
```

gives me a jQuery object, but not a real array;

I can do

```
var array = jQuery.makeArray($("#mydiv").find("span"));
```

and then use a for loop to put the id attributes into another array

or I can do

```
$("#mydiv").find("span").each(function(){}); //but i cannot really get the id and assign it to an array that is not with in the scope?(or can I)
```

Anyhow, I just wanna see if there is a shorthand in jQuery to do that;

Answer (score 167, accepted):

> //but i cannot really get the id and assign it to an array that is not with in the scope?(or can I)

Yes, you can!

```
var IDs = [];
$("#mydiv").find("span").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
```

This is the beauty of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures%20javascript).

Note that while you were on the right track, [sighohwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery/827320#827320) and [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery/827329#827329) both point out more reliable and concise ways of accomplishing this, taking advantage of [attribute filters](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeHas#attribute) (to limit matched elements to those with IDs) and jQuery's built-in [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function:

```
var IDs = $("#mydiv span[id]")         // find spans with ID attribute
  .map(function() { return this.id; }) // convert to set of IDs
  .get(); // convert to instance of Array (optional)
```

Comment: yeah, I didnt use a real array because technically you *can* put duplicate ID's in html even though its totally wrong to do that

Comment: @Deviant: true (although if you do that, you've made IDs kinda useless...)  Another reason my example isn't suitable for production code is simply that it does no filtering of elements - if Roy has any spans without IDs, he'll end up with empty elements in the array.

Comment: I use this function to get only the unique variables(screw duplicate id's, they won't work anyways on the second occurence) `$.unique($('[id]').map(function() { return this.id; }).get());` By wrapping it in $.unique it gets nicely filtered keeping your code clean :-)

Comment: Just complementing the answer, if you want to search all IDs from page using a certain string: $('*').each(function(){ if (/^stringhere/g.test(this.id)) { console.log(this.id) } });

Comment: Just a remember $.unique doesn't work with string nor numbers https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Answer (score 40):

The .get() method will return an array from a jQuery object. In addition you can use .map to project to something before calling get()

```
var idarray = $("#myDiv")
             .find("span") //Find the spans
             .map(function() { return this.id; }) //Project Ids
             .get(); //ToArray
```

Comment: I owe you a coffee mate!

Answer (score 13):

My suggestion?

```
var arr = $.map($("#mydiv [id]"), function(n, i) {
  return n.id;
});
```

you could also do this as:

```
var arr = $.map($("#mydiv span"), function(n, i) {
```

or

```
var arr = $.map($("#mydiv span[id]"), function(n, i) {
```

or even just:

```
var arr = $("#mydiv [id]").map(function() {
  return this.id;
});
```

Lots of ways basically.

Answer (score 7):

The best way I can think of to answer this is to make a custom jquery plugin to do this:

```
jQuery.fn.getIdArray = function() {
  var ret = [];
  $('[id]', this).each(function() {
    ret.push(this.id);
  });
  return ret;
};
```

Then do something like

```
var array = $("#mydiv").getIdArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a late answer but now there is an easy way. Current version of jquery lets you search if attribute exists. For example

```
$('[id]')
```

will give you all the elements if they have id. If you want all spans with id starting with `span` you can use

```
$('span[id^="span"]')
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a *real* array, but objs are all associative arrays in javascript.

I chose not to use a real array with [] and [].push because technically, you can have multiple ID's on a page even though that is incorrect to do so. So just another option in case some html has duplicated ID's

```
$(function() {

       var oArr = {};
       $("*[id]").each(function() {
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           if (!oArr[id]) oArr[id] = true;
       });

       for (var prop in oArr)
           alert(prop);

   });
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">
 <span id='span1'>
 <span id='span2'>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var IDs = [];
$("#mydiv").find("span").each(function(){ IDs.push($(this).attr("id")); });
```

Comment: Try adding a bit of explanatory text to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ids of specifict tags and send it to a annother element. For exemple:

```
$("input").map(function() {
    $( "textarea" ).append(this.id+"\n");
});
```

It will get all input ids and send it to textarea.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=1;i<13;i++)     
{

   alert($("#tdt"+i).val());  

}
```