# How to iterate through table with id='test' and get ids of each row inside table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to iterate through table with id='test' and get ids of each row inside table using JQuery ?
I need to  collect ids in array.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I think it is a legitamate question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var ids = $('table#test tr').map(function() {
   return this.id;
});
```

Comment: i think this is the most appropriate way to do this :)- +1

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
$('#test tr').each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B2jGu/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table#test tr').each(function() {    
     alert($(this).attr('id')); //here you can push these id's into an array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$("#test tr").each(function(){
    var row_id=$(this).attr("id");
    // Now do something with the row_id variable.
});
```

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

```
var TrIds = [];
$('#TableId tr').each(function() {
   TrIds[] = $(this).id();
});
```