# convert div ids to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to do this with one line of code.

```
    var a = '';
    $('#MyDivs div').each(function (){a+=this.id+',';});
    a = a.substring(0,a.length-1);// remove the last comma
```

I though something like this would do it, but to no avail. Am I on the right tracks??

```
    $('#MyDivs div[id]').join(', ');
```

Comment: try $(this).attr("id") instead of this.id

Comment: @RajatSinghal `$(this).attr('id')` is the same as `this.id` except the first is the jQuery way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all of the IDs with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go in one line:

```
var a = $('#MyDivs div[id]').map(function(){ return this.id }).get().join(', ');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tGFeZ/

Comment: nice, get() converts to an array.  Learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 2):

This should offer some assistance: [How to get all of the IDs with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery)

There is a one line example there, although it may not be the most attractive solution.

Comment: Thanks. I searched for at least 10 mins for an answer before posting. Guess I need to work on my search terms :/

Answer (score 2):

If by "one line" you mean a single statement, this isn't possible with this library.  If you're just looking for a condensed string of statements, the following will do it.  But even the following should be expressed in multiple lines for readability

```
$.makeArray($('#MyDivs div[id]').map(function(){return this.id})).join(',');
```

Same as below:

```
$.makeArray($('#MyDivs div[id]').map(function(){
    return this.id
}).join(',');
```