# Get array of values use JQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all of the IDs with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery)

How can i get array of values attribute ID inside "span id='enable'" if i use JQuery?

```
<span id='enable'>
<p id='105'>English</p>
<p id='250'>Spanish</p>
<p id='56'>German</p>
</span>
<span id='disable'>
<p id='38'>BlaBla</p>
<p id='46'>BlaBla2</p>
<p id='87'>BlaBla3</p>
</span>
```

Comment: I forgot to add: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use Jquery's `map` function. This will return array of "English","Spanish" and "German".

```
var myArray = $('#enable p').map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

For getting Id's list you can do this

```
var myArray = $('#enable p').map(function(){
       return this.id;
    }).get();
```

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B3LuE/

Comment: But i need array of attribute ID: 105, 250, 56

Comment: I've edited my answer and have written about that too.

Comment: @Chuck, you have to apply `map()` to `#enable p` or `#enable > p`, not to `#enable` itself.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want? If you want all the IDs that's a way to do it:

```
var ids = [];
$('#enable>p').each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
alert(ids);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late on this one:

```
$(function() {
 var x = $('#enable p');
 var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    arr.push(x[i].id);
 }
});​
```