# Using jQuery to extract value from a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a tic-tac-toe game with javascript. The issue is when I am checking to see if there are any winners on the board after each move.

When I run this jQuery function

```
$( "#row1")[0].innerHTML
```

The output is

```
"<span0>o</span0><span1>x</span1><span2>o</span2>"
```

Because each html element has a different span I'm not quite sure how to check without writing out all the possibilities. I have looked at SOF and found this [Get array of values use JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851307/get-array-of-values-use-jquery). It's quite similar but it doesn't account for the different span tags, e.g (span0, span1, span2).

I'm trying to see how I can only get the 'o','x','o' from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get you "oxo" in a string which you can then process however you see fit, you can use:

```
// gets you "oxo"
$( "#row1").text();
```

If you want those characters in an array, you could do this:

```
// gets you ["o", "x", "o"]
$( "#row1").text().split("");
```

Comment: Short answer, but your answer will fail if a span has text with more than one digit :)

Comment: @redV - These aren't digits.  These are "x" characters and "o" characters and no tic-tac-toe game I've ever seen allows more than one value per square and this solves the case the OP asked for.

Comment: +1 :) I am accepting my insanity and I learned a new thing today :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that those spans are valid html5 tags. Each of the span tags should just be . If you are using the individual span names to insert text into them, then it is better to do that by id eg . So wherever you are referencing $("span1") or $("#row1 span1") you would instead reference the id like this: $("#square1") in order to insert the x and o text. There are other ways to do this, but for these purposes it is probably just best to have 9 separate ids. This way the example in the link that you referenced to read them into an array is essentially what you need.

If you really don't want to do that, then add a give all of your span tags a class= 'box' class. eg:  . In this case the code to read into an array based on the example you provided in the link would have to change from $('#row1 span') to $('#row1 .box') (notice the period before "box". indicating that we are looking for classes, rather than tag names) I don't like this second solution, because it doesn't fix the invalid html5 tags.

I suppose there may be a way to use a wildcard to search all elements that begin with "span" but that would just be way more ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get it, we will loop through child span elements of #row1 and alert their text value (which is the inner text):

```
$("#row1").children().each(function()
({
   alert($("this").text());
});
```

Comment: You may want to notice that the OP is using elements like `<span0>` and `<span1>`, not `<span>`.

Comment: Yeah that produces a blank array. The only way I grab objects is when I specify <span0>, or <span1>

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pK25e/)

Below code will do the job

```
var html = "<span0>o</span0><span1>x</span1><span2>o</span2>";
var values = $.map($(html), function( n, i ) {
   return $(n).html();
});
console.log(values);
```