# How we get all ids of sibling div?

Tags: jquery

The design is like this

```
<div id="cat-11">Apple<span class='qty'>(12)</span></div>
<div id="cat-12">Samsung<span class='qty'>(22)</span></div>
<div id="cat-13">Moto G<span class='qty'>(55)</span></div>
<div id="cat-14">Google<span class='qty'>(16)</span></div>
<div id="cat-15">Nokia<span class='qty'>(100)</span></div>
```

I have span value of id for cat-13. I just want to some all span value of all siblings div?
plz assist assist me.

I tried like this:

```
$("#cat-13").sibling().find('span').val();
```

I know it will return single value but unable to get all vaules?

Comment: You want to get the value from all the div > spans ?

Comment: You want to **sum** the values?

Comment: `.val()` is for getting the value of an input.

Comment: Note that there's no `sibling` function : it's `siblings` (it returns all siblings).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all of the IDs with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery)

Comment: @Barmar: thanks, it is my mistake, i means was there .text()

Comment: Your title says you want all the IDs, but you accepted an answer that gets all the texts. Please correct the title if it's wrong.

Comment: @Barmar: According to my question ...@dystroy's answer is correct for me..and using this id i could get my expected result. And which I had accepted(answer of @empiric) that is the my expected result so I did accept but now I have changed the answer according to my question so there would not any confusion for other users who will come to this page.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all ids in an array you may do

```
var arr = $("#cat-13").siblings().map(function(){ return this.id }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to save all "values" in an array:

```
var values = []; //initialize array

$("#cat-13").siblings().find('span').each(function() { //iterate over all siblings
    values.push($(this).text()); //write text into array
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nwmoxwoe/1/)**

If you only want the numbers you can do something like the following:

```
 number = $(this).text().replace(/\D/g,''); //replace all non-digit-characters
 values.push(number);
```

But in this case, I would recommend using a `data-*`-attribute for the values.

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dff4uz8w/)**