# How can I send the new order of divs to my php script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use this code to create a drag and drop functionality for my Bootstrap application (I used jQuery, jQuery UI, and Bootstrap):

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var panelList = $('#draggablePanelList');

    panelList.sortable({
        // Only make the .panel-heading child elements support dragging.
        // Omit this to make then entire <li>...</li> draggable.
        handle: '.panel-heading',
        update: function() {
            $('.panel', panelList).each(function(index, elem) {
                 var $listItem = $(elem),
                     newIndex = $listItem.index();

                 $.post('ajax.php');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
    /* show the move cursor as the user moves the mouse over the panel header.*/
#draggablePanelList .panel-heading {
    cursor: move;
}
```

**And finally, HTML:**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="draggablePanelList">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel - 1.</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel - 2.</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel - 3.</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel - 4.</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel - 5.</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel - 6.</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel - 7.</div>
                <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

It works without any problem about drag and drop function. The issue is, I load the order of the panels from a database, and I want to save the new order of boxes to database after re-ordering them.

With $.post('ajax.php'), I am trying to send values to server, but how can I detect new order of items?

Besides, if you have any suggestion to make the code more "professional", please do not hesitate to give me your recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: You need to give each panel an ID, then send http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery