# Is there a way to use javascript or jquery to get the id names of all divs on a webpage? (inverse of "getElementByID")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop a chrome extension that would extract the id names of all the divs on a webpage, and display them over the div. Theoretically, it would work the inverse way as "getElementbyId". This is a for a UX design-research project. I'm rather new with javascript and jquery. Any kind of help would be welcome.

Comment: You should first try something, then ask a question if it doesn't work showing that code, those are the best questions for stack overflow. You can query for all divs, then that array will contain their ids. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: put some code there if you  have tried and if you haven't tried then do a bit of research. It is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery/827312

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[id]')).map(div => div.id)
```

That will return all divs with an id attribute, put it in an array, and then return only the ids

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```js
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var allIds = [];
for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
  var el = allElements[i];
  if (el.id) { allIds.push(el.id); }
}

console.log(allIds)
```

```html
<div id="1">hi</div>
<div id="2">hi</div>
<div id="3">hi</div>
<div id="4">hi</div>
<div id="5">hi</div>
<div id="6">hi</div>
<div id="7">hi</div>
<div id="8">hi</div>
<div id="9">hi</div>
<div id="10">hi</div>
```

Comment: @JuanMendes please don't edit people's answers to add/amend logic. By all means leave a comment to suggest changes, though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I wasn't aware we couldn't edit answers. Care to point to a meta link?

Comment: You can always edit an answer to improve the current answer(like fixing a type error or something like that), but adding your own idea/solution directly into the answer seem to me that it conflicts with the authors' intention. Imagine what would happen if everyone just edited others answers to add their own answer/solution.

Comment: @JuanMendes under the edit review options: *"**clearly conflicts with author's intent** This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."* - adding your own answer into an existing answer counts as *deviating from the original intent of the post*.