# getting specific data of selected row from Datatable

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, datatable

I'm desperately trying to get specific information from the selected rows using datatable jquery.
I want to get the data-ID attribute of the second column, but I only have access to the content of the cell.

```
var rows = table.rows({selected: true} ).data().toArray();
        for (let i in rows) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify( rows[i][1] )); //shows Jason
        }
```

```
<tr>
<th>Customer name</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
```

```
<tr id="1234">
<td data-id="553">Jason</td>
<td>Paris</td>
<td>$140</td>
</tr>
```

A solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `<tr>` node of each row using [`row().node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node()).

Once you have the `<tr>` node, you can access its ID:

```
table.rows( {selected: true} ).every( function () {
  rowNode = this.node();
  console.log( rowNode.id );
} );
```

There are different ways to iterate over your data - and I'm not sure how you are handling your "selected" rows in your specific case. But `row().node()` gives you what you need.

As an alternative, for multiple rows at once, there is [`rows().nodes()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()).

You can use something like [this jQuery approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827294/how-to-get-all-of-the-ids-with-jquery/827312) to build an array of IDs, also.

But all these variations use the DataTables row-related `node()` or `nodes()` API call. This means you can process the entire table - including rows which are not displayed (e.g. due to pagination).